# Fast Perlin/Simplex noise generator

Tags: python, numpy, perlin-noise

For my Minecraft-style voxel engine with world generation I have the chunking done as well as mesh building. Perlin noise generation for heightmap and caves I have to generate one point at a time with looping (Python noise library). I'm looking for a Perlin or Simplex noise implementation that:

- Can generate a chunk of noise at once instead of one point per call.
- Can generate starting from a specific coordinate.
- Can generate 2d or 3d noise.
- Is faster than Python noise library and looping.

Implementations I've seen either generate a chunk at a time but can't start at a specific coordinate, or can generate at a specific coordinate but only one point at a time.

What I have:

```
from noise import * # <-- noise library I'm using
import numpy as np

...
    def generate(self):
        gradient = [(i * 4) / CHUNK_HEIGHT for i in range(int(CHUNK_HEIGHT / 2), -int(CHUNK_HEIGHT / 2), -1)]
        self.blockIDs = np.zeros((CHUNK_WIDTH + 2, CHUNK_HEIGHT, CHUNK_WIDTH + 2), dtype='int16')

        @np.vectorize
        def caveNoiseGen(x, y, z):
            return 1 if (snoise3(x / 64, y / 64, z / 64, octaves=6) + (1.5 - (gradient[y]))) * 10 > 0 else 0

        @np.vectorize
        def heightNoiseGen(x, y, z):
            return 1 if (snoise3(x / 128 + snoise3(x / 8192, y / 8192, z / 8192, octaves=1), y / 8192,
                                 z / 128, octaves=6) +
                         (((snoise2(x / 512, z / 512, octaves=1) * 3) + 3) * gradient[y])) * 10 > 0 else 0

        time1 = time.perf_counter()
        self.blockIDs = np.zeros((CHUNK_WIDTH + 2, CHUNK_HEIGHT, CHUNK_WIDTH + 2), dtype='int16')
        x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(CHUNK_WIDTH + 2) + (self.position[0] * CHUNK_WIDTH) - 1,
                              np.arange(CHUNK_HEIGHT),
                              np.arange(CHUNK_WIDTH + 2) + (self.position[2] * CHUNK_WIDTH) - 1)
        caveNoise = caveNoiseGen(x, y, z)
        heightNoise = heightNoiseGen(x, y, z)
        print(caveNoise[5, 5, 5])
        for i in itertools.product(range(CHUNK_WIDTH + 2), range(CHUNK_WIDTH + 2)):
            for y in range(CHUNK_HEIGHT):
                self.blockIDs[i[0], y, i[1]] = int(heightNoise[y, i[0], i[1]] if caveNoise[y, i[0], i[1]] == 1 else 0)
            self.blockIDs[i[0], 0, i[1]] = 1

        print("generate: " + str(time.perf_counter() - time1))
```

Time to generate is around 0.08s but it causes a lag spike.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is often not faster than a pure Python code with clever loops and actually do not use SIMD instructions (ie. hardware vectorization capabilities). Try using the Numba's JIT. This will be much much faster with it.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard I actually tried Numba but it didn't like the noise functions I was using